# Azure Function - Azure Key Vault - Invalid URI

Tags: c#, azure, function, uri, azure-keyvault

I've got some problems with my Key Vault URL. The Code works and I get all my secrets, but my log always shows some Errors and I don't understand why. I was googling for the "memoryactivity, functionactivity" or why it says he can't parse the hostname, but I got no information that helps. So maybe some of

```cs
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            var aSecret = (await kv.GetSecretAsync($"https://{name}.vault.azure.net/", "aSecret")).Value;
            var bSecret = (await kv.GetSecretAsync($"https://{name}.vault.azure.net/", "bSecret")).Value;
```

Logs:

```sh
Failed to publish status to /memoryactivity
System.Private.Uri: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
Failed to publish status to /functionactivity
System.Private.Uri: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

Comment: I'm going to test it today! I will give you feedback soon. Thx for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting settings correctly, it can be merely a warning that can be ignored. But, if you want to know more about it, call [Uri.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads):

```
var original = $"https://{name}.vault.azure.net/", "aSecret";
if (!Uri.TryCreate(original, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
    //Log as insights to know which Uri and context are throwing error!
}
```

Comment: I added it as a new answer, so you can read the log easier.

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for your time :)

I got more information now.. But I'm still struggling to understand the problem.

```
Failed to publish status to /memoryactivityMS_FUNCTION_METRICS hostjsonfileconfigurationsource.loadhostconfigurationsource.initializehostconfig,0,0,0,2,3.0.15193.0,2021-03-26T11:24:24.7695267Z,
"{'IsStopwatchHighResolution:' True}",BACKUPS
```

Do I have an Option to get better logs at all ? I mean the Log output Is a bit ....

Cheers